# Why does my code give wrong values for variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I know the question is not very precise, and that is because I have no idea what is going on either. I have narrowed down the problem to a couple of lines, but to me the execution seems rather weird.

```
def loadmaze(backup):
    test = createmaze(10,10) #This creates a new 10x10 matrix
    maze = placewalls(test, "x") #The X is a string with wall positions
    if maze != test: 
    #when placewalls executed correctly, and returned a maze different from the original
        showmaze(maze) #simply printing maze to console
    else:
        return backup #so nothing changes, looks as if function never happened
    return maze,10,10
    # this returns the new maze, with walls, and the dimensions of the new maze
def placewalls(amaze,positions):
    #placing walls, definitely correct
    return amaze-with-walls
```

Obviously I changed the variable names so it's clear what I'm doing.
The problem is, when I call the function `loadmaze(maze)`, it never  returns a maze with walls. Somehow the `test` and `maze` values are always identical. I do not understand how this can be as the maze with walls is assigned to `maze` after `test`, which at that point does not have walls. 
According to the debug, `test` **also** contains the walls after the third line has been executed.
Please help, I'm terribly confused.

Comment: You'll need to show the real `placewalls` code. Clearly "somethinggoeswrong" is true so that it returns its first argument.

Comment: I'm certain somethinggoeswrong is false and it is in fact returning the correct maze including walls. remember that the backup does not have walls.

Comment: As already said by @Daniel, too little code to really say what goes wrong. But could it be the case that you are confused how Python passes variables around (and what variables are)? `maze` and `test` might be the same object, but now just with walls. See for example in the [Python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x).

Comment: Like @stephan said, looks like `# placing walls` subroutine modifies the object which the first parameter refers to. Please share the full code of the `placewalls` function.

Comment: I do know what variables are, but how can `test` be the same as `maze` when `maze` gets another value (with walls) after `test` has been assigned an empty maze?

Comment: Because you passed `test` to `placewalls` which likely modified it in place and returned it.

Comment: @Wh1spr: apologies, no intention to indicate that you don't know in general what a variable is. Just that you might be surprised what a variable is in Python. Depending on what `createmaze` returns and what you do inside `placewalls`, the variables `test`, `amaze`, `amaze-with-walls` and `maze` might all be references to the same object. And then `maze == test` is always true (since all variables refer to the same object).

Comment: I already tried placing an extra line `maze = test`, then using `maze = placewalls(maze, "x")`, it does not work

Comment: @stephan Ooooh, that makes a lot of sense... Thanks a lot, I have replaced `test` in the `placewalls` function call with a second `createmaze()` function call and it works as expected!

Comment: You may find the text & diagrams here helpful: [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @stephan said, the variables `test` and `maze` refer to the same objects in the memory. So I changed `maze = placewalls(test,"x")` with `maze = placewalls(createmaze(10,10),"x")`, thus creating a new object different from maze. This then results in test and maze being two different mazes.